# How to not lose the estimated effect of time-invariant variable using FE?

Tags: mixed-model, econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am currently researching whether there are any factors potentially driving up the level of Suspicious Activity Reports in the United States (got the idea from J. Braun - Drivers of Suspicious Transaction Reporting Levels, 2016). I found the part where the strictness of the country's regime could potentially have an effect on higher amount of SARs particularly interesting and would like to include that into my model as well.

So I got an idea to use the number of words in each of the state's regulatory text (obtained from State RegData) as the proxy for strictness. However, I have a panel dataset for each state ranging from 2014 to 2020, but the State RegData only provides numbers for 2020. Therefore, when I use fixed effects, I lose the estimate of the effect of strictness as it does not change over time. Is there any way to remedy this? Or would Random Effects or some mixed-effects model (Mundlak?) perhaps be more suitable?

I feel the need to mention that I am quite new to econometrics, so any advice would be much appreciated. Also, any tips on good control variables that I could include would be welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no requirement that a variable changes within groups in order to estimate a fixed effect for it. It will be a between-groups effect, rather than within.